# Preg_replace content with id

Tags: php, regex

I have the following subject:

`$subject = '[ta #12286152] c-d0-231-34 drop [#3414a43]';`

I want to match everything that have given id. My code is this but when put, `12286152` it is replaced okay, but when put `3414a43`, all subject was removed?

`echo preg_replace('/(\[)(.*?)3414a43(.*?)(\])/', '', $subject);`

I want to replace all in `[]`that have MY id.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: have you tried `[^\]]*` instead of the first `(.*?)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole subject got removed because the first `[` matched was the `[` next to `ta`, and `.*?` matched until the first `3414a43`. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD5oT8/1).

You need to use negated character class `[^][]` or `[^]]`:

```
/\[[^][]*3414a43[^][]*]/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO5lK9/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (`[^]]*` will match 0+ non-`]`s)
- `3414a43` - your ID
- `[^][]*` - ibid.
- `]`  - a literal closing `]` symbol (no need escaping it outside a character class)

Since you are not using captures, I suggest removing all the capturing group parentheses.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/XBnE97):

```
$id = "3414a43";
$str = "[ta #12286152] c-d0-231-34 drop [#3414a43]"; 
$result = preg_replace('~\[[^][]*' . $id . '[^][]*]~', '', $str);
echo $result;
```